# @Autowired annotation not working

Tags: spring, autowired

I'm trying to test the Autowire option like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applnContext.xml" })
public class Foo {
    @Autowired
    private Bar bar;

    public Bar getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(final Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Foo f = new Foo();
        System.out.println(f.getBar());
    }
}
```

and the config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="bar" class="entity.Bar"></bean>
    <context:annotation-config />

</beans>
```

But the `Bar` object is not getting injected. Am I missing anything here or doing something wrong?

Note that I'm specifying the applicationContext file using annotation on the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [@ContextConfiguration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html) attribute is part of the `org.springframework.test` package, so isn't going to work in the manner you've attempted to use it.  See [this post](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=75991) on the Spring forums for more details.

Answer (score 4):

If this is a unit-test, as it seems, add

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

And in your `applicationContext.xml` don't forget this (although in this case it is not the problem)

```
<context:component-scan base="org.basepackage" />
```